# Combining Java generics and reflection to avoid casting

Tags: java, generics, reflection, casting

I have some code like this:

```
Object doMethod(Method m, Object... args) throws Exception {
    Object obj = m.getDeclaringClass().getConstructor().newInstance();
    return m.invoke(obj, args);
}
```

The code I use is a little more complex, but that's the idea of it. To invoke `doMethod` I do something like this:

```
Method m = MyClass.class.getMethod("myMethod", String.class);
String result = (String)doMethod(m, "Hello");
```

This works just fine for me (variable number of arguments and all). **The thing that irks me is the necessary cast to `String` in the caller.** Since `myMethod` declares that it returns a `String`, I'd like `doMethod` to be smart enough to change its return type to also be `String`. Is there some way of using Java generics to accomplish something like this?

```
String result = doMethod(m, "Hello");
int result2 = doMethod(m2, "other", "args");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure,

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T> T doMethod(Method m, Class<T> returnType, Object Args ...) {
    Object obj = m.getDeclaringClass().getConstructor().newInstance();
    return (T) m.invoke(obj, args);
}

String result = doMethod(m, m.getReturnType(), "Hello");
```

One is idly curious about the architecture that calls for such a thing to be done, but that's well out of scope :)

If you don't like that you can also leave off the binding of returnType and the compiler will automatically cast it to whatever you're assigning the return type to.  e.g., this is legal:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T> T doMethod(Method m, Object Args ...) {
    Object obj = m.getDeclaringClass().getConstructor().newInstance();
    return (T) m.invoke(obj, args);
}
```

The cast will be to whatever you are attempting to assign it to, but I think most people would consider it suspect.

Comment: in the first example, use `returnType.cast(...)` instead of the unchecked cast to make it type safe.

Comment: +1 that second example is rather eerie, but intriguing. I'm adding type inference to my Java wish list.

Comment: That doesn't make it compile time type safe, it just hides the compiler warning.  If the return type of the method doesn't match what you passed in, it will still throw ClassCastException at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

I wish that Method had been parameterized to capture the return type. You could always do that yourself by wrapping Method with your own MethodEx... Doing so would allow you to provide some pretty nice facades too...

```
public class MethodEx<T> {
  private final Method _method;
  private final Class<T> _returnType;

  public MethodEx(Method method, Class<T> returnType) {
    _method = method;
    _returnType = returnType;
  }

  public T invoke(Object object, Object... args) throws InvocationTargetException {
    try {
      return _returnType.cast(_method.invoke(object, args));
    }
    // good opportunity to hide/wrap other exceptions if your 
    // usecases don't really encounter them
  }
}
```

This is just a starting point -- you can have factory methods on MethodEx that does a lot of up-front validation to make sure method is public, etc.

Finally, if you are caching the Method instances etc and dealing with dynamically loaded classes, this would also be a good opportunity to defensively introduce weak references (to the method and the return type) so you don't have to be as careful about pegging entire classloaders throughout your code.

Comment: +1 This approach is very tantalizing, but even here the return type must be explicitly passed to the constructor.

Comment: @Dan you are right -- but you can write a factory method that hides that ugliness too. But in the end, you can't keep passing the buck -- at compile time, you don't always know what the return type of a method invoked through reflection is, so no amount of trickery will get us to fully type checked. All the approaches discussed help reduce the number of places where the unchecked warnings need suppressing.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
public <T> T doMethod(Method m, Class<T> clazz, Object... args);
```

Although it moves the cast to the routine itself. In general what you're trying to do doesn't sound like good practice. Reflection itself incurs some performance overhead, but perhaps that not of concern?

Comment: The reason was to wrap some boilerplate around the method invocation. There seem to be varying opinions on the gravity of the performance overhead; I'm willing to sacrifice a little performance for a lot of code reuse, but it may turn out that the performance hit is unacceptable.